# Create a ts R object from a CSV file with dates as a column with multivariate series

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a CSV file with the format

```
ref_date;wings;airfoil;turbines
2015-03-31;123,22;22,77;99,0
2015-04-30;123,22;28,77;99,0
2015-05-31;123,22;22,177;02,0
2015-06-30;56,288;22,77;99,0
```

and I want to use the `forecast` package to predict the next values of this time series. The `forecast` package only accepts a `ts` object, but so far all my attempts to create one failed. I tried to

1) Use zoo package

```
df = read.zoo(data_file, sep=';', dec=',', format="%Y-%m-%d", header=T)
```

but the data is truncated at the decimal point.

2) Use the zoo package with xts

```
df = read.zoo(datafile, sep=';', dec=',', format="%Y-%m-%d", header=T)
df_ts = ts(df)
```

The dates are nowhere to be seen, the index is just a sequence of numbers, like

```
1 123.22 22.77 99
```

3) Use read.csv and ts

```
df = read.zoo(datafile, sep=';', dec=',', format="%Y-%m-%d", header=T)
df_ts = ts(df)
```

4) Try using xts

```
df = read.csv(data_file, sep=';', header=T, dec=',')
tt = as.xts(df[,-1],order.by = as.Date(as.character(df[,1]), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
forecast(tt) 
Error in `tsp<-`(`*tmp*`, value = tsp.y) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified
```

the result looses all information about the date, including the ref_date column, and now the forecast package gives nonsense as result.

What is the correct approach to create the object that the `forecast` library is waiting and can generate a forecast, maintaining the dates, including in the plots?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you think truncation occurs with the first method? I tried it on the sample and it didn't seem to loose precision. It did complain about having duplicate dates. What version of `zoo` did you use? I tested with `zoo_1.7-14 `.

Comment: Same version as yours. I don´t have repeated dates, fixing it now.

Comment: The read.zoo command with the data shown works for me but note that it produces a zoo object, not a data.frame which the name `df` might suggests.

Comment: So what is the best procedure to convert a CSV file with ISO dates to a object (dataframe? zoo? ts?) that can be used with the forecast package, that generates a graph with dates, not integer indexes?

Answer (score 1):

I have been wrestling CSV data into ZOO/XTS objects and sympathize -- painful.

Suggest using `as_xts()` in the `tidyquant` package

```
as_xts(read_csv(file),ref_date)
```

You may need to coerce the resulting `coredata()` in the `XTS` object back to numeric.

Comment: You might switch over to `timetk::tk_xts()`, which is replacing `tidyquant::as_xts()`. It's more robust and auto-detects date columns which is nice.